# What does vcpkg stand for?

Tags: c++, vcpkg

As the GitHub page describes it, vcpkg is a "C++ Library Manager for Windows, Linux, and MacOS":
https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg

But what does this name, "vcpkg", mean? I'm guessing "pkg" is short for "package", but what is "vc"?

Thanks

Comment: Visual C++ [some characters]

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I find it hard to remember sequences of letters that seem completely random to me. It's surprising that I couldn't find the answer to this question in the tool's readme, nor in its readthedocs page.

Comment: Probably means "Visual C(++)" but could also be Version Control. Unlikely to be Vice Chairman, Victoria Cross or Venture Capital.